# How best to organise python and non-python files in Windows subsystem for Linux 2?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I normally divide my work files into a directory for each project, containing both python code and non-python files e.g. reports that I edit in office programs. I've recently moved to a Windows computer and have been trying to work with its subsystem for Linux (v2 i.e. WSL2). I need to run my python code in this, as some modules I need are not available in Windows. However, if I put my documents in the Windows file system and set my PYTHONPATH to include my python code directories there, python in WSL2 is very slow to load - I suppose this is because it's trying to access Windows files and they need to be "translated" to be used in Linux.

I'm wondering is there a way to let Linux read my python code quickly whilst keeping it together with my non-python files for each project and making it possible to edit those other files in Windows office applications? For example, I'm wondering if some setup with soft links between Linux and Windows directories could be possible, but I've not worked out a way.

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem in a test environment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1260611/edit) to provide a step-by-step example so we can experience the issue.

Comment: Just to report - for now I've copied the python code into the Linux file system and use the Linux directories in my PYTHONPATH. Then I will periodically sync them to the Windows directories. I think this should work well enough for now, though it's a bit inelegant.

@user535733 Thanks for replying. I will see if I can come up with an example like that later.